# URLSession dataTask completionHandler does not work in playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I watched a tutorial from youtube and tried that tutorials. Then I write
the code in playground file and I got no result but there is no error.
Thus I make a new Project in XCode. Then add a Button to Main.StoryBoard and connect the UI to code. After doing all necessary things I runthe project in simulator and everything go well and I can see all the work inside completion handler. Following is the code in XCode project.

```
@IBAction func doNetwork(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("start network jobs...")
    // url
    let url: URL! = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.12/swnet.php")
    URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
    // url session
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        print("Handler")
        if let respData = data {
            print("Data")
            print(respData)
        }
        if let resp = response {
            print("Resp")
            print(resp)
        }
        if let err = error {
            print("Error")
            print(err)
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Following is the code in playground.

```
// url
let url: URL! = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.12/swnet.php")
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
// url session
let session = URLSession.shared
let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    print("Handler")
    if let respData = data {
        print("Data")
        print(respData)
    }
    if let resp = response {
        print("Resp")
        print(resp)
    }
    if let err = error {
        print("Error")
        print(err)
    }

})

task.resume()
```

Comment: @creeperspeak The question is my post title "URLSession dataTask completionHandler does not work in playground"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell the playground to continue execution long enough for your async code to complete. To do that:

```
import PlaygroundSupport 

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

From [Apple's docs on this property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage):

> By default, all top-level code is executed, and then execution is
>   terminated. When working with asynchronous code, enable indefinite
>   execution to allow execution to continue after the end of the
>   playground’s top-level code is reached. This, in turn, gives threads
>   and callbacks time to execute.